# Failing to deploy webapp in tomcat using maven cargo

Tags: web-applications, maven-2, tomcat, maven-cargo

I am trying to deploy a webapplication using `maven` `cargo` plugin into `tomcat` server.

But i am getting the below error when i am running the command `mvn cargo:deploy` in the command prompt.

> [INFO] Failed to deploy
>   [C:\Users\Ramesh\workspace\SimpleSpringMvcExample\target
>   \SimpleSpringMvcExample.war] FAIL -
>   Encountered exception
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   C:\Program Files\Apa che Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat
>   6.0\webapps\SimpleSpringMvcExample.war (Access is  denied)

***pom.xml***

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.SimpleSpringMvcExample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleSpringMvcExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SimpleSpringMvcExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    .....

    <build>
        <finalName>SimpleSpringMvcExample</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                        <type>remote</type>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>runtime</type>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.tomcat.manager.url>http://localhost:8080/manager</cargo.tomcat.manager.url>
                            <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                            <cargo.remote.password>admin</cargo.remote.password>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                    <deployer>
                        <type>remote</type>
                        <deployables>
                            <deployable>
                                <groupId>com.SimpleSpringMvcExample</groupId>
                                <artifactId>SimpleSpringMvcExample</artifactId>
                                <type>war</type>
                            </deployable>
                        </deployables>
                    </deployer>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

***tomcat-users.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>

<tomcat-users>
<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager" />
</tomcat-users>
```

maven ***settings.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>
  <servers>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

I think i gave the correct id & password of tomcat admin in the `pom.xml` But dont know whats wrong?

***It was working fine..but suddenly started throwing this error...after i used the maven-tomcat-plugin for one of the sample spring projects..***

I dont know if it has anything to do with this...

Please help me in locating the problem..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it appears that there is an issue with permissions - maven does not seem to have permission placing the .war file in tomcat's webapps folder.

Are you on Vista/Windows 7 with UAC turned On?

Comment: I googled for UAC an turned it off and now it is working fine..Thanks buddy.